# How to append new attribute to config object in Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework, zend-config

I want to check if available a some attribute in config object and if not, add new attribute to config object in bootstrap. How ever is it possible ?

example :-

```
$options['allowModifications'] = true;
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini( APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/clientsettings.ini', null, $options);

if (!isset($config->offers->default)) {
    $config->offers->default = "Best Available Rate";
}

Zend_Registry::set('clientSettings', $config);
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized a solution,

```
$options['allowModifications'] = true;
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini( APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/clientsettings.ini', null, $options);

if (!isset($config->offers->default)) {
    $offers = ['default' => "Best Available Rate"];
    $config->offers = $offers;
}

Zend_Registry::set('clientSettings', $config);
```

but finally i thought this is not a good idea, allowing config object to modification.